# War not generated by gradle for Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have simple spring boot application and it runs as standalone app. I started conversion to WAR using online guides.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}

war {
    baseName = 'simulator'
    version =  '1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker")
    compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.23'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Initializer:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Assembling:

```
c:\dev\projekty\Simulator>gradlew war
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:war
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3.96 secs
```

But there is no war created. Why?

Comment: how about `gradlew build`.

Comment: What makes you think there is no war created? Where did you look for it? The output says the war task was executed, so the war should be at `build/distributions/`.

Comment: I found one war in build\libs\knz-simulator-1.0.0.war. Is this target war?

Comment: Build contains following directories: classes, libs, resources, tmp. There is no target or dist directory in top directory.

Comment: Depends on how you configured the `war` task and the project. By default the war of the war task added by the war plugin should be in `build/distributions/`, but it could be that spring boot reconfigures this. You can output the target path of the war in your build script to see where it is generated.

Comment: Gradle configuration is in the question. How can I print the output  path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `war` is probably generated, just not at the place where you expect it. Add to your build script

```
logger.lifecycle "war.archivePath = $war.archivePath"
```

and it will log where you can find the WAR.

Comment: Simulator>gradlew build
war.archivePath = Simulator\build\libs\simulator-1.0.0.war. Strange path.

Comment: Why do you think it is a strange path, what would you have expected?

Comment: I was seeking for some target or dist directory. Libs seems to me like intermediary directory where libraries are placed before packaging.

Comment: That is true. As I said, the default path for the `war` task that is added by the `war` plugin is `build/distributions/`. So something must have changed it. I guess it is the spring boot plugin because it does something with the war to produce the final result. But I don't know spring boot, so I don't know.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 6):

In my case, using `spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE` and `Gradle 4.2`, for some reason the `bootWar` wasn't being triggered by `gradlew war`. So, I just executed the command below and the war file was generated:

```
./gradlew bootWar
```

Answer (score 5):

SpringBoot disable war task. Just re-enable it in the script. I didn't like BootWar which was creating lib-provided folder and other org folder classes for traditional war deployment.

```
war {
    enabled= true
}
```